# color_continuous_scale a valid function for plotly python?

Tags: plotly

I was creating a Gantt chart for my school project and while changing the color scheme of the bars I used the following line

```
chart.update_layout(title_font_size=42, font_size=10, title_font_family="Proxima Nova", color_continuous_scale=[(0, "red"), [0.5, "yellow", (1, "green")]])
```

and the error it is showing is

> ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type
> plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'color' and all the properties of plotly
> Bad property path: colour_continuous_scale

Answer (score 2):

- using sample code as base https://plotly.com/python/gantt/#gantt-charts-and-timelines-with-plotlyexpress to make re-producible example
- `color_continuous_scale` is a parameter to **plotly express**
- to use `update_layout()` you need to use **graph objects** parameter structure. Hence `coloraxis={"colorscale":[...])`
- both are demonstrated below

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        dict(Task="Job A", Start="2009-01-01", Finish="2009-02-28", Completion_pct=50),
        dict(Task="Job B", Start="2009-03-05", Finish="2009-04-15", Completion_pct=25),
        dict(Task="Job C", Start="2009-02-20", Finish="2009-05-30", Completion_pct=75),
    ]
)

fig = px.timeline(
    df,
    x_start="Start",
    x_end="Finish",
    y="Task",
    color="Completion_pct",
    color_continuous_scale=[(0, "pink"), (0.5, "blue"), (1, "purple")],
)
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Demo",
    title_font_size=42,
    font_size=10,
    title_font_family="Proxima Nova",
    coloraxis={"colorscale": [(0, "red"), (0.5, "yellow"), (1, "green")]},
)
```